# Continuous stopping time property

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

> Let $S,T$ be continuous stopping time with respect to filtration $\mathcal{G}_t$. If $\Lambda\in \mathcal{G}_{S\lor T}$, then $\Omega\cap \{S\leq T\}\in \mathcal{G}_T$

This problem is from Diffusion Markov Process and Martingale. Here is what I try...

$\Lambda\in \mathcal{G}_{S\lor T}$ iff $\Lambda\cap \{S\leq t\} \cap \{T\leq t\}\in \mathcal{G}_t$.

$\Lambda\cap \{S\leq T\}\in \mathcal{G}_{ T}$ iff $\Lambda\cap \{S\leq T\} \cap \{T\leq t\}\in \mathcal{G}_t$

So I try to write $S\leq T$ as $\{S\leq r\}\cap \{r\leq T\}$ where $r\in \mathbb{R}$. But from here I don't know how to preceed.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thankes in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured out myself..

Let $A\in \mathcal{F}_{S\lor T}$. we have
\begin{align*}
A\cap \{S\leq T\}\cap \{T\leq t\} = [A\cap \{S\leq t\}\cap \{T\leq t\}]\cap [\{S\leq T\}\cap \{T\leq t\}]
\end{align*}
The first part is in $\mathcal{F}_T$. We know that
\begin{align*}
\{S>T\}\cap \{T\leq t\}=\cup_{q\in \mathbb{Q}^+\cap [0,t]}(\{S>q\}\cap \{T\leq q\}\cap \{T\leq t\})
\end{align*}
The RHS is in $\mathcal{F}_T$. Since $(T\leq t)\in \mathcal{F}_t$, we get $\{S\leq T\}\cap \{T\leq t\}\in \mathcal{F}_t$.